# Clickable dataframe rows to trigger a detailed display streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

main_data = {
    'name': ['Xavier', 'Ann', 'Jana', 'Yi', 'Robin', 'Amal', 'Nori'],
}
row_labels = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107]
df_main = pd.DataFrame(data=main_data, index=row_labels)

data = {
    'name': ['Xavier', 'Ann', 'Jana', 'Yi', 'Robin', 'Amal', 'Nori'],
    'city': ['Mexico City', 'Toronto', 'Prague', 'Shanghai',
             'Manchester', 'Cairo', 'Osaka'],
    'age': [41, 28, 33, 34, 38, 31, 37],
    'py-score': [88.0, 79.0, 81.0, 80.0, 68.0, 61.0, 84.0]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=row_labels)
st.dataframe(df_main)
```

The result is as follows:

I have two questions:
the first one is :
I want when I click on any rows to show the details information in df dataframe and the second one is I want to show the dataframe completely without scrolling.

Comment: Check out st-aggrid for the clickable dataframe functionality https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-aggrid/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `st_aggrid` to do this and here is one way you can do it. You don't need two dataframes, and you can just use one `df` but only display to users relevant fields.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import GridOptionsBuilder, AgGrid, GridUpdateMode, ColumnsAutoSizeMode


data = {
    'row_labels': [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107],
    'name': ['Xavier', 'Ann', 'Jana', 'Yi', 'Robin', 'Amal', 'Nori'],
    'city': ['Mexico City', 'Toronto', 'Prague', 'Shanghai',
             'Manchester', 'Cairo', 'Osaka'],
    'age': [41, 28, 33, 34, 38, 31, 37],
    'py-score': [88.0, 79.0, 81.0, 80.0, 68.0, 61.0, 84.0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# select the columns you want the users to see
gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df[["row_labels", "name"]])
# configure selection
gb.configure_selection(selection_mode="single", use_checkbox=True)
gb.configure_side_bar()
gridOptions = gb.build()

data = AgGrid(df,
              gridOptions=gridOptions,
              enable_enterprise_modules=True,
              allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
              update_mode=GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED,
              columns_auto_size_mode=ColumnsAutoSizeMode.FIT_CONTENTS)

selected_rows = data["selected_rows"]

if len(selected_rows) != 0:
    col1, col2, col3, col4 = st.columns(4)

    with col1:
        st.markdown("##### Name")
        st.markdown(f":orange[{selected_rows[0]['name']}]")
    with col2:
        st.markdown("##### City")
        st.markdown(f":orange[{selected_rows[0]['city']}]")
    with col3:
        st.markdown("##### Age")
        st.markdown(f":orange[{selected_rows[0]['age']}]")
    with col4:
        st.markdown("##### Py Score")
        st.markdown(f":orange[{selected_rows[0]['py-score']}]")
```